# how to convert xml to database table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, xml

## input:

```
Declare @OUT xml
select @OUT = N'
<row>
  <kind>MainCat</kind>
  <sortid>1</sortid>
  <kind_id>1</kind_id>
  <PPoet>حافظ</PPoet>
  <MTitle>حافظ</MTitle>
  <Row>1</Row>
</row>'
```

```
select T.X.value('@Kind', 'nvarchar(50)') as kind,
T.X.value('@sortid', 'int') as sortid
from @out.nodes('/row') as T(X)

this select return NULL!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very close:

```
select 
  T.X.value('./kind[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as kind,
  T.X.value('./sortid[1]', 'int') as sortid
from @out.nodes('/row') as T(X);
```